# How to use reactive statements to fetch data from a +server.js handler in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to fetch data from a `+server.js` handler like this:

```
<script>
  let subject = "Svelte";

  let message = "";

  // Why does this produce an error?
  $: fetch(`/api/?subject=${subject}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => (message = data.message));
</script>

<input bind:value={subject} />

{message}
```

but I receive this error:

> Error: Cannot call `fetch` eagerly during server side rendering with relative URL (/api/?subject=Svelte) — put your `fetch` calls inside `onMount` or a `load` function instead

I modeled that page after [this REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/16e48fadc6ac4f21aa9a6befc3bde66d?version=3.3.0) which *does* work, but uses an absolute URL to a remote endpoint. I need to fetch data from a `+server.js` endpoint.

I don't think the `+server.js` code matters in this case, but here it is just in case:

```
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export async function GET({ url }) {
  const subject = url.searchParams.get("subject");
  return json({ message: `Hello, ${subject}!` });
}
```

According to the error message, I must put the `fetch` call inside `onMount` or a `load` function.

Putting the code inside `onMount` eliminates the error, but the `fetch` is not reactive. Instead, the `fetch` only executes once and never updates. In addition, I get the following warning:

> $: has no effect outside of the top-level

So if `fetch` calls must be inside `onMount` or `load`, and `$` must be top-level, how do I fetch data from the `+server.js` endpoint in a reactive way?

I create a [GitHub repository with the reproducible example](https://github.com/travishorn/sveltekit-reactive-fetch-issue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it onMount as suggested, then also bind to the input event on the input which can call your fetch again. Repl here: https://svelte.dev/repl/7c31ebd09e95420385e3c94385a4fb1e?version=3.59.1

Edit: You could also do this:

$: if (browser) fetch(`/api/?subject=${subject}`)

Comment: Thanks! While this technique doesn't fully capture the behavior of reactive statements, it does work great for small projects like this. In a large app where `subject` could be modified in several places, I just have to remember to trigger `load()` in each case.

Comment: btw, the browser come's from: 
import { browser } from "$app/environment";

and here the same issues from github svelte:
https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/8536